# KeyFrame object

Tags: keyframes

I'm doing an assignment on a 20 second animation. so far I have a car that's driving for the first 10 seconds and then I have built a rocket (Which I am stuck on). The way I want it to be done is that the car drives for the ten seconds and then the rocket lifts on just as the car stops. Is there any way I can set a specific keyframe for when the rocket can follow the path it it supposed to go?

Answer (score 1):

[Keyframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/introduction.html) connect a value with a frame, if the keyframe locates the rocket on the ground at frame 100 and in the stars at frame 200 then it will stay on the ground until frame 100 then start moving at from 101 until it reaches the location given at frame 200.

The steps for animating are - move to the desired frame, position object, add a keyframe. The [dopesheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html) and the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html) can be used to alter the keyframes after they have been created. The dopesheet allows you to adjust the timing by only altering the frame that a value is keyframed on while the dopesheet also lets you alter the way values are calculated between keyframes as well as adding modifiers and drivers to calculate the keyframed values.

If you are making a child object follow a path, you can keyframe the [evaluation time](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/properties/data.html#path-animation) property of the path to define when the object is at the beginning and end of the path. The [follow path constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html) also has an offset property that can be animated for the same result.

Comment: What.. thanks mate, this might take me a while to process and understand but thank you.

Comment: Right, first.. my car and my rocker are on ground at frame 1. how do I set the frame for rocket to start at frame 200?

Comment: and my rocket followed a Bezier curve path so do I select the rocket or the path?

Comment: If you have the rocket follow a path, then animate the evaluation time in the curve properties.  The [timeline](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/timeline.html) is the easiest place to alter the current frame.